# Apple mach O linker Xcode iOS

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Have this Error, plese send me code correct thanks

Loook code debug:  http://textsnip.com/3jrghq (copy/pasted code below:)

symbols for architecture arm64:

```
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_PFUser", referenced from: objc-class-ref in LoginViewController.o  
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_PFPush", referenced from: objc-class-ref in ParseExampleAppDelegate.o  
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_PFInstallation", referenced from: objc-class-ref in ParseExampleAppDelegate.o  
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_PFQuery", referenced from: objc-class-ref in ViewController.o  
      objc-class-ref in ParseExampleViewController.o  
      objc-class-ref in Buongiorno.o  
      objc-class-ref in ParseImageViewController.o  
      objc-class-ref in Compleanno.o  
      objc-class-ref in Buonanotte.o  
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Parse", referenced from: objc-class-ref in ParseExampleAppDelegate.o  

     (maybe you meant: _OBJC_CLASS_$_ParseImageViewController, _OBJC_CLASS_$_ParseExampleViewController , _OBJC_CLASS_$_ParseExampleAppDelegate , _OBJC_CLASS_$_ParseExampleCell )
```

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Thanks

If can please write code correct

Comment: This is a very common issue and I'm assuming you didn't search at all before posting. Be a good citizen and search first, but to avoid being that guy, I'll still answer.

Answer (score 1):

Which version of Parse are you using? arm64 support was not included until v1.2.15 and you are trying to include it in an arm64 binary. I'd update the library version or just run it in the non-64 bit simulator.

Comment: You need to update the Parse framework, when did you download this version? The 64-bit version should have been available for a year.

Comment: can send link for dowload?

Comment: What version do you have and where did you get it?

Answer (score 0):

Now the framework has been updated. You can have solutions of this warnings.

Just download the latest framework from this [Link](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/PushTutorial).

As of 1st Feb 2015, apple will not approve the apps without supporting architecture arm64.

In order to work this for parse, you have to update the framework.

This works for me. Hope it help someone else also.

Thanks...